# Why do the nilpotent and diagonalizable parts commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

As part of an exercise I needed to decompose the Jordan form of a complex matrix into nilpotent and diagonalizable parts, and also explain why they commute. The decomposition is trivial since strictly triangular matrices are nilpotent, but I don't see - why do these matrices commute?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274980/prove-that-nd-dn-where-d-is-a-diagonalizable-and-n-is-a-nilpotent-matrix?rq=1

Comment: In the context of Jordan form decomposition, it is often a question of block diagonal/nilpotent matrices. For every Jordan block, commuting of a nilpotent and a matrix of the form $\lambda I$ is not a problem.